# global error handling middleware in expressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What exactly am i doing wrong here. I am trying to create a global error handling middleware which shows **error message** and **error status** in a specific json format but instead it is showing error in some weird way.

- DIR: node/app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//gloabl error handling middlware
const globalError = require('./middleware/globalErrorHandlingMiddleware')

//middlewares
app.use(express.json())
app.use(globalError)


//homepage
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("homepage")
})

//page not found
app.all('*',(req,res,next)=>{
    const err = new Error('route does not exist')
    err.statusCode = 404;

    next(err)
})

//port
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server started at port 3000')
})
```

- DIR: node/middleware/globalErrorHandlingMiddleware.js

```js
function globalErrorHandler(err, req, res, next){
    
    const errorMessage = err.message || 'Something went wrong.';
    const statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;

    res.status(statusCode).json({
        error: errorMessage,
    });
};

module.exports = globalErrorHandler
```

[image: output i am getting]

[image: output expected]

Comment: Please add the error messages as text and not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to change the placement of your global error catcher, as the [documentation mentions](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html), it has to be at the end of your routes, in your example

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//gloabl error handling middlware
const globalError = require('./middleware/globalErrorHandlingMiddleware')

//middlewares
app.use(express.json())


//homepage
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("homepage")
})

//page not found
app.all('*',(req,res,next)=>{
    const err = new Error('route does not exist')
    err.statusCode = 404;

    next(err)
})


app.use(globalError) // moving to the end of your route calling

//port
app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('server started at port 3000')
})
```

you will find that

```http
@HOST = http://localhost:3000

GET {{HOST}}/2
Content-Type: application/json
```

will output

```http
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 32
ETag: W/"20-fEiG2Eve04KkBKDozkc9tU0brWo"
Date: Wed, 26 Jul 2023 10:53:14 GMT
Connection: close

{
  "error": "route does not exist"
}
```